# Need help on how to design table border correctly in CSS

Tags: css

To be straightforward: I'm trying to make a table in CSS looking similar to this:

[Taken from the terraria fandom wiki]
[image]

I got basically everything even with my very limited knowledge, but I'm failing on one thing: the borders between the columns.

Using this code:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
}
 
th {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

td + td { 
    border-left:1px solid black;
}
```

I managed to almost re-create it.

[This is how it looks]
[image]

The only solution I found to the dashed column border is setting border-collapse to collapse, but when I do this the padding between the border around the entire table and its content disappears.

[How it looks like with borders collapsed]
[image]

So how can I have both the padding AND the continuous column border? Thanks in advance.

Comment: produce a snippet here of what you have. include html

Comment: Did you try `cellspacing="0"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `border-spacing: 0;` to the table.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 3px;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

th+th {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

td+td {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

tr+tr>td {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>asdkljhad</td>
      <td>sdfkjfs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>38924</td>
      <td>095434539</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```